# load external javascript only when needed

Tags: javascript

I have reference to bunch of javascript file on my page which are used by different functions calls.

When I load the page, first all external JS files get loaded.

Is there anyway so that they get called only when function call occurs for that .js file?

Comment: You can use third party library like `steal.js`, http://bitovi.com/blog/2010/09/stealjs-script-manager.html

Comment: Can you please clarify how "bunch of php files" are related to loading/running JavaScript? Small sample of resulting HTML may help...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: typo. Corrected!

Comment: You mean you need to load only related javascript files when you are using their functions?

Comment: Then why don't you only load those script file in php files when you are in need of them. Is there a specific reason you need it to be done in javascript dynamic loading?

Answer (score 1):

You can add your conditions to this method, which allows you to dynamically add an external javascript file:

```
    function loadScript(url, callback){

    var script = document.createElement("script")
    script.type = "text/javascript";

    if (script.readyState){  //IE
        script.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                    script.readyState == "complete"){
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback();
            }
        };
    } else {  //Others
        script.onload = function(){
            callback();
        };
    }

    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

By using JQuery

```
$.getScript("//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js")
```

Comment: TS want get files for only needed function.

Comment: Sridhar: I could not understand the concept!

Comment: Can you please exaplain how does it help?

Comment: whenever you need to load just cal the function with required url it will call

Comment: Thank you so much sir! The loadScript function is exactly what I needed. Only thing I added was a check to see if the callback function is defined.

Answer (score 0):

No simple way for get JS fyle for function "on-fly". Also, for load file for function system need some time. May be good solution will using minification for JS-files?

Comment: How minification. Minimal file are must to loaded!

Comment: I think what Eugene is saying is that if you compress your Javascript files well, they'll be small enough that you don't need to worry about just transferring everything to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You may try some as this.

```
loadExternalScriptFile = function(filename, callback) {
    var fileref = document.createElement("script");
    if (fileref){
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
        fileref.onload = callback;
        if (typeof fileref != "undefined")
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
    }
}

var functionMap = {
    'function1': 'js/f1.js',
    'function2': 'js/f1.js',
    'function3': 'js/f3.js'
};


function checkFunction(functionName, callback) {
    if (typeof window[functionName] !== 'function') {
        loadExternalScriptFile(functionMap[functionName], callback);
        return;
    }
    callback();
    return;
}



//Using

checkFunction('function1', function(){
    function1(params);
});
```

But i think loading all in minification version and single file is better.